# How to create a new array of objects based on the values of two existing arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, key-value

I have a data set like so where there can be many objects in the array:

```
tableCols = [
    {
        "id": 50883,
        "header": "ABC",
        "operator": "Sum",
        "order": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 50884,
        "header": "Leakage",
        "operator": "Sum",
        "order": 3
    },
     .....
]
```

And I have another data set like so where there can be many objects in the array:

```
dataArr = [
    {
        "id": 925095,
        "grid_row_id": 170712,
        "grid_col_id": 50883,
        "data": "10",
        "error_msg": null,
        "locked": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 926137,
        "grid_row_id": 170712,
        "grid_col_id": 50884,
        "data": "34",
        "error_msg": null,
        "locked": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 926137,
        "grid_row_id": 170713,
        "grid_col_id": 50883,
        "data": "22",
        "error_msg": null,
        "locked": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 926137,
        "grid_row_id": 170713,
        "grid_col_id": 50884,
        "data": "100",
        "error_msg": null,
        "locked": 1
    },
    .....
]
```

Note that every single grid_col_id in the second array exists as an id in the first array.

I want to create another array like so:

```
formattedData = [
    {
        "ABC": 10,
        "Leakage": 34,
        ....
    },
    {
        "ABC": 22,
        "Leakage": 100,
        ....
    },
    ....
]
```

Essentially, for every item in dataArr, for all objects with the same grid_row_id, create an object in a new array where we have new key-value pairs where the key is equal to the header in tableCols where grid_col_id = id.

For example, in the dataArr above, we have 4 known objects, with grid_row_ids 170712 and 170713 (note that there could be more). The first object has grid_row_id 50883, which in tableCols with the id 50883 has headed ABC, so a new key is created the key as ABC and the value as 10 (because data = 10 in the dataArr object).

Hence why we have the following in formattedData:

```
"ABC": 10,
```

I have something which kind of works but it creates a new object for each item in dataArray instead of filtering through the array and creating a new object for every row:

```
        let ogGrid = [];
        let formattedData = [];
        let newObj = {};

        dataArr.forEach(row => {
                tableCols.forEach(element => {
                    if(row.grid_col_id === element.id)
                        newObj[element.header] = Number(row.data);
                });
            })
            ogGrid = {...newObj};
            formattedData.push(ogGrid);
        });
```

How would I be able to achieve the new structure?

Comment: I don't understand how you got that leakeage value. I thought you wanted to create this new array based on the id shouldn't it look more like this? `formattedData = [{ "ABC": 10, "ABC": 22 },     { "Leakage": 34, "Leakage": 100,}]`

Comment: The leakage is 34 and ABC is 10 for the first object because the first two items in the dataArr have the same "grid_row_id": 170712, so they go in the same object. The second item in dataArr has grid_col_id 50884, which in tableCols with the same value as the id has "header": "Leakage". Back in the dataArr, we have "data": 34. So Leakage: 34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a map to translate a column id to a header name, and another map to translate a row id to an (initially empty) object.
Then traverse the data to populate those objects with the help of these two maps.
Finally extract the objects into an array.

```js
const tableCols = [{"id": 50883,"header": "ABC","operator": "Sum","order": 2},{"id": 50884,"header": "Leakage","operator": "Sum","order": 3},];
const dataArr = [{"id": 925095,"grid_row_id": 170712,"grid_col_id": 50883,"data": "10","error_msg": null,"locked": 1},{"id": 926137,"grid_row_id": 170712,"grid_col_id": 50884,"data": "34","error_msg": null,"locked": 1},{"id": 926137,"grid_row_id": 170713,"grid_col_id": 50883,"data": "22","error_msg": null,"locked": 1},{"id": 926137,"grid_row_id": 170713,"grid_col_id": 50884,"data": "100","error_msg": null,"locked": 1},];

const headerMap = new Map(tableCols.map(({id, header}) => [id, header]));
const rowMap = new Map(dataArr.map(({grid_row_id}) => [grid_row_id, {}]));
for (const {grid_row_id, grid_col_id, data} of dataArr) {
    rowMap.get(grid_row_id)[headerMap.get(grid_col_id)] = +data;
}
const data = [...rowMap.values()];

console.log(data)
```

Comment: good old master js trincot to the rescue. You even made it look easy. thanx pal, I was also struggling trying to solve the issue with .map but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

```js
let ogGrid = {};
let formattedData = [];
let newObj = {};

dataArr.forEach(row => {
  if (!ogGrid[row.grid_row_id]) {
    ogGrid[row.grid_row_id] = {};
  }

  tableCols.forEach(element => {
    if (row.grid_col_id === element.id) {
      ogGrid[row.grid_row_id][element.header] = Number(row.data);
    }
  });
});

for (let id in ogGrid) {
  formattedData.push(ogGrid[id]);
}

console.log(formattedData);
```

```html
<script>
  const tableCols = [{
      "id": 50883,
      "header": "ABC",
      "operator": "Sum",
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 50884,
      "header": "Leakage",
      "operator": "Sum",
      "order": 3
    }
  ]

  const dataArr = [{
      "id": 925095,
      "grid_row_id": 170712,
      "grid_col_id": 50883,
      "data": "10",
      "error_msg": null,
      "locked": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 926137,
      "grid_row_id": 170712,
      "grid_col_id": 50884,
      "data": "34",
      "error_msg": null,
      "locked": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 926137,
      "grid_row_id": 170713,
      "grid_col_id": 50883,
      "data": "22",
      "error_msg": null,
      "locked": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 926137,
      "grid_row_id": 170713,
      "grid_col_id": 50884,
      "data": "100",
      "error_msg": null,
      "locked": 1
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).